# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value Treeview Error using vb.net sqlserver

Tags: vb.net

I am simple sales system using vb.net with treeview control. I am loading data from sqlserver database. treeview is loaded successfully.
When I clik the order id on treeview node relavent customerdetails and shipping details need to be display on the datagridview.
I attched the screen shot image below. if I select order id relavent customer information and shipping information displayed well. But I click another nodes error displayed

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhQ5F.jpg)

```
Private Sub TreeView1_AfterSelect(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.AfterSelect
    Dim Sql As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim Sql1 As SqlDataAdapter

    Sql = New SqlDataAdapter("select a.Customerid,CompanyName, Address, City,Country,Phone from Customers a , Orders b where a.customerid=b.customerid and b.orderid=@pk ", ConString)

    Sql1 = New SqlDataAdapter(" select shipName, ShipAddress,ShipCountry,Freight from orders  where orderid=@pk ", ConString)
    Sql.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pk", SqlDbType.NChar, 10))
    Sql.SelectCommand.Parameters("@pk").Value = e.Node.Text
    Sql1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@pk", SqlDbType.NChar, 10))
    Sql1.SelectCommand.Parameters("@pk").Value = e.Node.Text

    Dim ds2 As New DataSet
    Dim ds3 As New DataSet

    Sql.Fill(ds2, "Customers")
    Sql1.Fill(ds3, "orders")

    DataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables(0)
    DataGridView2.DataSource = ds3.Tables(0)
End Sub
```

This code writen for loading the treeview

```
While Reader1.Read()
    OrderNumber = Reader1("orderid")
    ChildNode = New TreeNode(OrderNumber)
    RootNode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode)

    CustomerInfo = New TreeNode("Customer Information")
    ChildNode.Nodes.Add(CustomerInfo)
    Command2.Parameters("@a").Value = OrderNumber
    Reader2 = Command2.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Reader2.Read()

    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("Customerid"))
    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("CompanyName"))
    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("Address"))
    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("City"))
    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("Country"))
    CustomerInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader2("Phone"))
    Reader2.Close()

    ShipInfo = New TreeNode("Shipping Details")
    ChildNode.Nodes.Add(ShipInfo)
    Command3.Parameters("@a").Value = OrderNumber
    Reader3 = Command3.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
    Reader3.Read()

    ShipInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader3("shipName"))
    ShipInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader3("ShipAddress"))
    ShipInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader3("ShipCountry"))
    ShipInfo.Nodes.Add(Reader3("Freight"))
    Reader3.Close()

    Connection2.Open()
    Connection3.Open()
End While
TreeView1.ExpandAll()
```

Comment: Check the value of e.Node.Text at the line Sql1.SelectCommand.Parameters("@pk").Value = e.Node.Text.  The error is showing that parameter is not set.  Also shouldn't Sql.Fill(ds3, "orders") be Sql1.Fill(ds3, "orders")?

Comment: The parameterized query '(@pk nchar(10))select a.Customerid,CompanyName, Address, City,Co' expects the parameter '@pk', which was not supplied. error displayed sir. i edited code above